# Devise Custom Controller not creating record in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

This was working, but I've made a change somewhere and now cannot get it to work. I have a nested form to create a company along with the first contact that uses Devise. The company record is being created but the contact (devise model) isn't being created. If I create the company and then add a contact to the company, the contact is created so I'm pretty sure the controller works. Need another set of eyes to spot my mistake.

Error: 
RuntimeError in CompaniesController#create
Could not find a valid mapping for nil

CompaniesController (relevant methods):

```
  class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_contact!, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]



   # GET /companies/new
  def new
   @company = Company.new
   @company.contacts.build
  end


  # POST /companies
  # POST /companies.json
  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        sign_in(@company.contacts.first)
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name, :legal_entity, :KVK_number, :VAT_number, :KVKdoc, contacts_attributes:[:first_name, :last_name, :address, :phone, :email, :postcode, :password] )
    end
  end
```

Contacts Registration Controller:

```
class Contacts::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
# This is a custom controller that inherits from the standard Devise Registration Controller. 
# This controller is used as the user is added to the existing account not it's own account.

# Skips the standard Devise authentication filter to allow for an active user session to create a user recorod.
skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication

# Custom method to ensure that the user on the page has an active session to ensure that the account is accessable.
before_filter :has_current_contact


# Create method is just a call to the standard Devise create method
def create
  super
end

protected

# Stop the user sessisons from being switched to the new user
def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
  true
end

# Test to see that the person on the page has an active session
def has_current_contact
  if current_contact.nil?
    redirect_to root_path, alert: 'You need to be logged in to do this!' 
  end
end

# Sets the permited params for the registration. Inherits the standard devise parameters defined in the 
# application controller and merges the account id of the current user.
def sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_up).merge(company_id: current_contact.company_id)
end
```

end

I can see that the code throws the error on the attempt to find a contact for the company and sign in since it can't find a contact given that none has been created, but can't figure out why it's not being created.

Help?

Comment: "This was working, but I've made a change somewhere and now cannot get it to work." don't you use Git version control?

Comment: I do and so far looking at diff's I haven't seen a change that would relevantly change this function.

Comment: Ok, so if you have git and commit often enough, then go back in history (using checkout) to last moment when this worked and reapply every change until you find what is causing the problem. That's the easiest way to do it and you will learn some useful debugging in the process :)

Comment: In the process of doing that - 17 commits to weed through - was hoping someone would see an obvious error, but going to have to do it the hard way. Lesson always run your full tests suite :)

Comment: I've just seen your question and didn't have time to dig into (lot of code here!) so tried to give you any help. But if tests catch that your task is a little easier, you can write a ruby script to go commit by commit and run tests on every changeset!